# Spin operators on 2 spin half particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space

> I have been given the operator:
>   $$
> S_{12}=3(\sigma_1.e)(\sigma_2.e)-\sigma_1.\sigma_2,
> $$
>   where $e$ is a unit vector connecting the 2 particles and $\sigma_i$ is the pauli vector operator acting on particle $i$.
>
> Show for a system is a singlet state that:
>   $$
> S_{12}|\Psi\rangle=0.
> $$

---

so,  $$|\Psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} }(|+\rangle\otimes|-\rangle-|-\rangle\otimes|+\rangle).$$

What I assume happens is:

$$
S_{12}|+\rangle\otimes|-\rangle=3(\sigma_1.e)|+\rangle\otimes(\sigma_2.e)|-\rangle-\sum_i \sigma_{1i}|+\rangle\otimes\sigma_{2i}|-\rangle
$$

However this on the singlet state doesn't get $0$

How does this $S_{12}$ operator work?

Comment: Is it $S_{12} = 3 (\sigma_1\cdot e)(\sigma_2\cdot e) +\sigma_1 \cdot \sigma_2$ or $S_{12} = 3 (\sigma_1\cdot e)(\sigma_2\cdot e) - \sigma_1 \cdot \sigma_2$?

Comment: The tensor operator  defined with negative sign as pointed out by secavara

Comment: Honestly, now you have the sign right and also you have written how the operator works accurately on $|+-\rangle$. If you do the math carefully you'll get the result. Remember picking $e$ to be a normalized vector. You can pick $e=\{\sin \theta \cos \phi, \sin \theta  \sin \phi,\cos \theta\}$, for instance, or even just $e=\{0,0,1\}$ to begin with. You can also use a computational too.

Comment: I only managed to get it to work if $e=0$ which would imply that the spin aligns along this unit vector.

Comment: Actually is this correct:

$$\sigma.e|+\rangle=(cos\theta,sin\theta e^{i\phi})$$

If not, how does it work?

Comment: Yes, you have $e \cdot \sigma=\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos \theta       & \mathrm{e}^{-i\phi} \sin \theta \\
    \mathrm{e}^{i\phi} \sin \theta       & -\cos \theta 
\end{bmatrix}$ and therefore $e \cdot \sigma |+\rangle$ gives the result you have there.

Comment: The moment you chose + and - eigenstates, you've implicitly rotated to the z-axis. You've no doubt learned that the [Dirac exchange operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Relation_with_the_permutation_operator) $P_{12}=(\vec{\sigma}_1\cdot \vec{\sigma}_2 +I)/2$ has eigenvalue - on the (antisymmetric!) singlet, so $-\vec{\sigma}_1\cdot \vec{\sigma}_2|\Psi\rangle=3|\psi\rangle$, cancelling $3\sigma_1^z\sigma _2^z|\Psi\rangle=-3|\Psi\rangle$.

Answer (score 2):

The space of the 2-particle system is the 4-dimensional Hilbert space $\:\mathbb{C}^{4}=\mathbb{C}^{2}\boldsymbol{\otimes}\mathbb{C}^{2}$, the product space of the two 1-particle system spaces $\:\mathbb{C}^{2}$.

If for the particles we use the symbols $\:\alpha,\beta\:$ instead of $\:1,2\:$ then the single state $\:\Psi\:$ mentioned in the question is a complex 4-dimensional vector and more exactly
\begin{equation}
\Psi \sim 
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}_{\!\alpha}
\!\!\!\otimes\!
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}_{\!\beta}
\!\!\!-\!\!
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}_{\!\alpha}
\!\!\!\otimes\!
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}_{\!\beta}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}_{\!\alpha\beta}
\!\!\!\!\!-\!\!
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}_{\!\alpha\beta}
\!\!\!=
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\!-\!}0\:\:\\
\hphantom{\!-\!}1\:\:\\
\!-\!1\:\:\\
\hphantom{\!-\!}0\:\:
\end{bmatrix}_{\!\alpha\beta}
\tag{01}
\end{equation}
andthe operator $\:S_{\alpha\beta} \equiv S_{12}\:$ is sum of operator products as follows : 
\begin{equation}
S_{\alpha\beta}=3\left(\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{\alpha}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{e}\vphantom{\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{\beta}}\right)\boldsymbol{\otimes}\left(\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{\beta}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{e}\right)-\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{\alpha}\boldsymbol{\otimes}\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{\beta}
\tag{02}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{\alpha}\boldsymbol{\otimes}\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{\beta}\equiv \sigma^{\alpha}_{1}\otimes\sigma^{\beta}_{1}+\sigma^{\alpha}_{2}\otimes\sigma^{\beta}_{2}+\sigma^{\alpha}_{3}\otimes\sigma^{\beta}_{3}
\tag{03}
\end{equation}
Without loss of generality<sup>1</sup> we may suppose that 
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{e}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{04}
\end{equation}
and (02) gives
\begin{equation}
S_{\alpha\beta}=2\sigma^{\alpha}_{1}\otimes\sigma^{\beta}_{1}-\sigma^{\alpha}_{2}\otimes\sigma^{\beta}_{2}-\sigma^{\alpha}_{3}\otimes\sigma^{\beta}_{3}
\tag{05}
\end{equation}
Now,
\begin{align}
 \sigma^{\alpha}_{1}\otimes\sigma^{\beta}_{1} & = 
   \begin{bmatrix}         
         0&\hphantom{-}1\\
         1&\hphantom{-}0
   \end{bmatrix}
   \otimes
  \begin{bmatrix}         
         0&\hphantom{-}1\\
         1&\hphantom{-}0
   \end{bmatrix}
   =
   \begin{bmatrix}         
       \hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}\color{blue}{\bf 1}\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}\color{blue}{\bf 1}&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}\color{blue}{\bf 1}&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}\color{blue}{\bf 1}&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}       
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{06.1}\\
\sigma^{\alpha}_{2}\otimes\sigma^{\beta}_{2} & = 
   \begin{bmatrix}         
         0&-i\\
         i&\hphantom{-}0
   \end{bmatrix}
   \otimes
  \begin{bmatrix}         
         0&-i\\
         i&\hphantom{-}0
   \end{bmatrix}
   =
   \begin{bmatrix}         
       \hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&-\color{blue}{\bf 1}\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}\color{blue}{\bf 1}&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}\color{blue}{\bf 1}&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
       -\color{blue}{\bf 1}&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}       
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{06.2}\\
\sigma^{\alpha}_{3}\otimes\sigma^{\beta}_{3} & = 
   \begin{bmatrix}         
         1&\hphantom{-}0\\
         0&-1
   \end{bmatrix}
   \otimes
  \begin{bmatrix}         
         1&\hphantom{-}0\\
         0&-1
   \end{bmatrix}
   =
   \begin{bmatrix}         
       \hphantom{-}\color{blue}{\bf 1}&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}0&-\color{blue}{\bf 1}&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&-\color{blue}{\bf 1}&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}\color{blue}{\bf 1}\hphantom{-}       
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{06.3}
\end{align}
so
\begin{equation}
S_{\alpha\beta}=2
\begin{bmatrix}         
       \hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}1\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}1&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}1&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}1&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}       
   \end{bmatrix}
\!-\!
\begin{bmatrix}         
       \hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&-1\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}1&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}1&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
       -1&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}       
   \end{bmatrix}
\!-\!
\begin{bmatrix}         
       \hphantom{-}1&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}0&-1&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&-1&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}1\hphantom{-}       
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{07}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
S_{\alpha\beta}=
\begin{bmatrix}         
       -1&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}3\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}1&\hphantom{-}1&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}1&\hphantom{-}1&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}3&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&-1\hphantom{-}       
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{08}
\end{equation}
and finally
\begin{equation}
S_{\alpha\beta}\Psi\sim
\begin{bmatrix}         
       -1&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}3\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}1&\hphantom{-}1&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}1&\hphantom{-}1&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}3&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&-1\hphantom{-}       
   \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
\hphantom{-}1\hphantom{-}\\
-1\hphantom{-}\\
\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{09}
\end{equation}

---

**EDIT**

<sup>$^{1}$
To be sure that equation (09) is valid in general let

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{e}=
\begin{bmatrix}
e_{1}\\
e_{2}\\
e_{3}
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{3},\quad \Vert\mathbf{e}\Vert^{2}=e_{1}^{2}+e_{2}^{2}+e_{3}^{2}=1
\tag{ed-01}
\end{equation}
From equations (06)
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{\alpha}\boldsymbol{\otimes}\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{\beta}\equiv \sigma^{\alpha}_{1}\otimes\sigma^{\beta}_{1}+\sigma^{\alpha}_{2}\otimes\sigma^{\beta}_{2}+\sigma^{\alpha}_{3}\otimes\sigma^{\beta}_{3}=
\begin{bmatrix}         
       \hphantom{-}1&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}0&-1&\hphantom{-}2&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}2&-1&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}1\hphantom{-}       
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{ed-02}
\end{equation}
Now
\begin{align}
\left(\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{\alpha}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{e}\vphantom{\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{\beta}}\right)\boldsymbol{\otimes}\left(\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{\beta}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{e}\right) & =
\begin{bmatrix}         
 e_3 &  \left(e_1-i e_2\right) \vphantom{\dfrac12} \\
 \left(e_1+i e_2\right) & -e_3  \vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{\otimes}
\begin{bmatrix}         
 e_3 &   \left(e_1-i e_2\right) \vphantom{\dfrac12} \\
\left(e_1+i e_2\right) & -e_3  \vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\nonumber\\
& =
\begin{bmatrix}         
 \hphantom{\left(e_1\:\,\, i e_2\right)}e_3 \begin{bmatrix}         
 e_3 &   \left(e_1-i e_2\right) \\
 \left(e_1+i e_2\right) & -e_3  \vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix} 
&   \left(e_1-i e_2\right)\vphantom{\dfrac12} \begin{bmatrix}         
 e_3 &   \left(e_1-i e_2\right) \\
 \left(e_1+i e_2\right) & -e_3  \vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix} \\
 \left(e_1+i e_2\right)\vphantom{\dfrac12} \begin{bmatrix}         
 e_3 &   \left(e_1-i e_2\right) \\
 \left(e_1+i e_2\right) & -e_3  \vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix} & \hphantom{\left(e_1\!e_2\right)}-e_3 \begin{bmatrix}       
 e_3 &   \left(e_1-i e_2\right) \\
 \left(e_1+i e_2\right) & -e_3  \vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}   \vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\nonumber\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}         
       e_3^{2} & \left(e_3e_1-i e_3e_2\right) & \left(e_1e_3-i e_2e_3\right) & \left(e_1-i e_2\right)^2 \vphantom{\dfrac12} \\
       \left(e_3e_1+i e_3e_2\right) & -e_3^{2}& \left(e_1^{2}+e_2^{2}\right)  & -\left(e_1e_3-i e_2e_3\right)\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
       \left(e_1e_3+i e_2e_3\right) & \left(e_1^{2}+e_2^{2}\right)  & -e_3^{2} & -\left(e_3e_1-i e_3e_2\right) \vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
       \left(e_1+i e_2\right)^2  & -\left(e_1e_3+i e_2e_3\right) & -\left(e_3e_1+i e_3e_2\right) & e_3^{2} \vphantom{\dfrac12}      
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{ed-03}
\end{align}
that is
\begin{equation}
\left(\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{\alpha}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{e}\vphantom{\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{\beta}}\right)\boldsymbol{\otimes}\left(\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{\beta}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{e}\right) =
\begin{bmatrix}         
       e_3^{2} & \left(e_3e_1-i e_3e_2\right) & \left(e_1e_3-i e_2e_3\right) & \left(e_1-i e_2\right)^2 \vphantom{\dfrac12} \\
       \left(e_3e_1+i e_3e_2\right) & -e_3^{2}& \left(e_1^{2}+e_2^{2}\right)  & -\left(e_1e_3-i e_2e_3\right)\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
       \left(e_1e_3+i e_2e_3\right) & \left(e_1^{2}+e_2^{2}\right)  & -e_3^{2} & -\left(e_3e_1-i e_3e_2\right) \vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
       \left(e_1+i e_2\right)^2  & -\left(e_1e_3+i e_2e_3\right) & -\left(e_3e_1+i e_3e_2\right) & e_3^{2} \vphantom{\dfrac12}      
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{ed-04}
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
S_{\alpha\beta}=
\begin{bmatrix}         
       \left(3e_3^{2}-1\right) & 3\left(e_3e_1-i e_3e_2\right) & 3\left(e_1e_3-i e_2e_3\right) & 3\left(e_1-i e_2\right)^2 \vphantom{\dfrac12} \\
       3\left(e_3e_1+i e_3e_2\right) &  -\left(3e_3^{2}-1\right)& 3\left(e_1^{2}+e_2^{2}\right)-2  & -3\left(e_1e_3-i e_2e_3\right)\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
       3\left(e_1e_3+i e_2e_3\right) & 3\left(e_1^{2}+e_2^{2}\right)-2  & -\left(3e_3^{2}-1\right) & -3\left(e_3e_1-i e_3e_2\right) \vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
       3\left(e_1+i e_2\right)^2  & -3\left(e_1e_3+i e_2e_3\right) & -3\left(e_3e_1+i e_3e_2\right) & \left(3e_3^{2}-1\right) \vphantom{\dfrac12}     
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{ed-05}
\end{equation}
or 
\begin{equation}
S_{\alpha\beta}=
\begin{bmatrix}         
       \left(3e_3^{2}-1\right) & 3\left(e_3e_1-i e_3e_2\right) & 3\left(e_1e_3-i e_2e_3\right) & 3\left(e_1-i e_2\right)^2 \vphantom{\dfrac12} \\
       3\left(e_3e_1+i e_3e_2\right) &  -\left(3e_3^{2}-1\right)& -\left(3e_3^{2}-1\right) & -3\left(e_1e_3-i e_2e_3\right)\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
       3\left(e_1e_3+i e_2e_3\right) & -\left(3e_3^{2}-1\right)  & -\left(3e_3^{2}-1\right) & -3\left(e_3e_1-i e_3e_2\right) \vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
       3\left(e_1+i e_2\right)^2  & -3\left(e_1e_3+i e_2e_3\right) & -3\left(e_3e_1+i e_3e_2\right) & \left(3e_3^{2}-1\right) \vphantom{\dfrac12}     
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{ed-06}
\end{equation}
and again in general
\begin{equation}
S_{\alpha\beta}\Psi\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{ed-07}
\end{equation}
Note that from equations (01) and (ed-02) we have
\begin{equation}
\left[\!\!\left[\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{\alpha}\boldsymbol{\otimes}\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{\beta}\right]\!\!\right]\Psi=
\begin{bmatrix}         
       \hphantom{-}1&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}0&-1&\hphantom{-}2&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}2&-1&\hphantom{-}0\hphantom{-}\\
       \hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}0&\hphantom{-}1\hphantom{-}       
   \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\!-\!}0\:\:\\
\hphantom{\!-\!}1\:\:\\
\!-\!1\:\:\\
\hphantom{\!-\!}0\:\:
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\!-\!}0\:\:\\
\!-\!3\:\:\\
\hphantom{\!-\!}3\:\:\\
\hphantom{\!-\!}0\:\:
\end{bmatrix}
=-3\Psi
\tag{ed-08}
\end{equation}
while from equations (01) and (ed-04) we have
\begin{equation}
\left[\!\!\left[\left(\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{\alpha}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{e}\vphantom{\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{\beta}}\right)\boldsymbol{\otimes}\left(\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{\beta}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{e}\right)\right]\!\!\right]\Psi=
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\!-\!}0\:\:\\
\!-\!\left(e_1^{2}+e_2^{2}+e_3^{2}\right)\:\:\\
\hphantom{\!-\!}\left(e_1^{2}+e_2^{2}+e_3^{2}\right)\:\:\\
\hphantom{\!-\!}0\:\:
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\!-\!}0\:\:\\
\!-\!1\:\:\\
\hphantom{\!-\!}1\:\:\\
\hphantom{\!-\!}0\:\:
\end{bmatrix}
=-\Psi
\tag{ed-09}
\end{equation}
that is the lhs expression $\:\left[\!\!\left[\left(\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{\alpha}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{e}\vphantom{\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{\beta}}\right)\boldsymbol{\otimes}\left(\boldsymbol{\sigma}^{\beta}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{e}\right)\right]\!\!\right]\Psi\:$ *is independent of the choice of the unit vector* $\:\mathbf{e}$.</sup>

Comment: but there is loss of generality assuming $e=(1,0,0)$ as it is now perpendicular to the direction if spin

Comment: @Toby Peterken : Have you appreciated what the scalar products of the 3-vectors $\hat e$ and $\vec \sigma$ mean, and how they transform under a 3-rotation? secavara solved the problem for you in excruciating, painful, detail. Why don't you just rotate $\hat{e}\to \hat{z}$, plug in, and check?